# Paperclip-ffmpeg not working on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ffmpeg, paperclip

I installed Paperclip-ffmpeg and tried to upload a flv file, but it seems there are some problems converting the file.

I added `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"` (I got the path by using `which ffmpeg`) to my `config/environments/development.rb` file, following the instructions on the paperclip-ffmpeg github page.

Here is my model `subquestion.rb`, which contains a paperclip field called qflv:

```
class Subquestion < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
    has_many :qimages , :dependent =>  :destroy

    has_attached_file :qflv, styles: {
        medium: {geometry: "640*480", format: 'flv'},
        thumb: {geometry: "100*100#", format: 'jpg', time: 10}
    }, processors: [:ffmpeg]
```

And here is my `_subquestion_fields.html.erb` file, where users upload videos:

```
<%= f.file_field :qflv %>
```

`_subquestion_fields.html.erb` is rendered by question.html.erb file:

```
<%= nested_form_for @question, :url => {:action => 'create_question'} do |f| %>
       <%= f.fields_for :subquestions do |builder| %>
       <%= render 'subquestion_fields', :f => builder %>
```

And here is part of the error message:

```
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /run/user/li/keyring-CsW4u8/pkcs11: No such file or directory
ffmpeg version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-1ubuntu2, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 30 2013 22:23:21 with gcc 4.7.2
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
[flv @ 0x8ba50a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, flv, from '/tmp/03000201005171FC8274A20623ECA86B119768-56C7-7A62-DB7A-A4B599F64EE720130727-1837-13757l9.flv':
  Metadata:
    metadatacreator : modified by youku.com in 20111202
    hasKeyframes    : true
    hasVideo        : true
    hasAudio        : true
    hasMetadata     : true
  Duration: 00:05:25.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 448x336 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 15 tbr, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
Incorrect frame size
Failed to set value '0x0' for option 's'
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /run/user/li/keyring-CsW4u8/pkcs11: No such file or directory
ffmpeg version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-1ubuntu2, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 30 2013 22:23:21 with gcc 4.7.2
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
[flv @ 0x86490a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, flv, from '/tmp/03000201005171FC8274A20623ECA86B119768-56C7-7A62-DB7A-A4B599F64EE720130727-1837-13757l9.flv':
  Metadata:
    metadatacreator : modified by youku.com in 20111202
    hasKeyframes    : true
    hasVideo        : true
    hasAudio        : true
    hasMetadata     : true
  Duration: 00:05:25.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 448x336 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 15 tbr, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
Incompatible pixel format 'yuv420p' for codec 'mjpeg', auto-selecting format 'yuvj420p'
[buffer @ 0x864c180] w:448 h:336 pixfmt:yuv420p
[scale @ 0x8653840] w:448 h:336 fmt:yuv420p -> w:448 h:336 fmt:yuvj420p flags:0x4
[crop @ 0x864dc20] w:448 h:336 -> w:0 h:0
[crop @ 0x864dc20] Invalid too big or non positive size for width '0' or height '0'
Error opening filters!


Started POST "/test_geisinger/roots/questions/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-27 23:12:31 -0400
Processing by RootsController#create_question as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EiJk5dBf1nL96BtUiKc0qALCg0Bj9mQ0dx9IodfYdO0=", "question"=>{"explanation"=>"flv", "choice_id"=>"8", "correct_selection_id"=>"32", "quiz_id"=>"10", "subquestions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"subquestion_type"=>"flv", "_destroy"=>"false", "qflv"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x9d94640 @original_filename="03000201005171FC8274A20623ECA86B119768-56C7-7A62-DB7A-A4B599F64EE7.flv", @content_type="video/x-flv", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"question[subquestions_attributes][0][qflv]\"; filename=\"03000201005171FC8274A20623ECA86B119768-56C7-7A62-DB7A-A4B599F64EE7.flv\"\r\nContent-Type: video/x-flv\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20130727-1837-1f6g2s0>>}}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] ffmpeg -i "/tmp/03000201005171FC8274A20623ECA86B119768-56C7-7A62-DB7A-A4B599F64EE720130727-1837-13757l9.flv" 2>&1
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] Command Success
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] Making...
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] Building Destination File: '03000201005171FC8274A20623ECA86B119768-56C7-7A62-DB7A-A4B599F64EE720130727-1837-13757l9' + 'flv'
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] Destination File Built
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] Adding Geometry
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] Extracting Target Dimensions
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] Target Size is Available
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] Keeping Aspect Ratio
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] Resize
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] Convert Options: 0x0
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] Adding Format
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] Adding Source
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] Building Parameters
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] -i :source -s 0x0 -y :dest
Command :: ffmpeg -i '/tmp/03000201005171FC8274A20623ECA86B119768-56C7-7A62-DB7A-A4B599F64EE720130727-1837-13757l9.flv' -s 0x0 -y '/tmp/03000201005171FC8274A20623ECA86B119768-56C7-7A62-DB7A-A4B599F64EE720130727-1837-13757l920130727-1837-11o3enh.flv'
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Error: error while processing video for 03000201005171FC8274A20623ECA86B119768-56C7-7A62-DB7A-A4B599F64EE720130727-1837-13757l9: Command 'ffmpeg -i '/tmp/03000201005171FC8274A20623ECA86B119768-56C7-7A62-DB7A-A4B599F64EE720130727-1837-13757l9.flv' -s 0x0 -y '/tmp/03000201005171FC8274A20623ECA86B119768-56C7-7A62-DB7A-A4B599F64EE720130727-1837-13757l920130727-1837-11o3enh.flv'' returned 1. Expected 0
```

There might be some problems with pkcs11 so I found this article:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=783568

But I could not find `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-*.desktop`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you think this is related to PKCS11? Look at the error message:

```
Invalid too big or non positive size for width '0' or height '0'
```

If you look at the command you generate, it tries to encode a video with a size of 0×0 pixels:

```
ffmpeg -i ….flv -s 0x0 -y ….flv
```

This is also what Paperclip tells you:

```
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] Convert Options: 0x0
```

You need to set a positive size for the video—any is fine, but leaving out `-s` entirely if you don't want to rescale would be the ideal option. I think the following should suffice:

```
has_attached_file :qflv, styles: {
    medium: {geometry: "640x480", format: 'flv'},
    thumb: {geometry: "100x100#", format: 'jpg', time: 10}
}, processors: [:ffmpeg]
```

Note the use of `x` and not `*` to specify the dimensions.

---

Not related to your question, but please look at the line that says:

```
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
```

You're using a broken and misnamed version of `ffmpeg` that originates from [Libav](http://libav.org/), not [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). Hundreds of bugs have been fixed since the release of this version, so consider updating yours. Look at the [FFmpeg download page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) for a few options.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I was actually using a gem called `rails-ffmpeg`, so if I changed the "misnamed ffmpeg" to FFmpeg, is the gem going to be affected?

Comment: I cannot find any Gem called `rails-ffmpeg`. What do you mean by "affected", exactly? I'm pretty sure the Gem does not ship its own `ffmpeg` binary, so it'll probably work with others as well.

Comment: Oh sorry, it is [paperclip-ffmpeg](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg). Thank you!!

Comment: What I mean by "affected" is whether or not do I need to change the do some changes to `paperclip-ffmpeg`. For example, if the misnamed ffmpeg and the real FFmpeg uses different command line instructions, then we sure have to change the gem. A really newbie question, perhaps.

Comment: Unless Paperclip uses egregiously wrong `ffmpeg` commands, nothing needs to be changed. Newer `ffmpeg` versions have a few more restrictions on what syntax can be used, and dropped some options like `-sameq`, but it should be trivial to fix if you run into any issues. The wrapper is rather small: https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg/blob/master/lib/paperclip_processors/ffmpeg.rb